# Emacs font settings not working in new frame

Tags: emacs, fonts

I'm trying to get comfortable with emacs. I installed [emacs starter kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit). Now I'm trying to customize fonts. In `~/.emacs.d/init.el` I did `(set-frame-font "-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--12-120-75-75-m-70-iso8859-1")`. It is working fine untill I do `C-x 5 2`. The new frame gets created with fonts, that were on the system before my customization. How do I override this behaviour to use only fonts I specify in init.el? Should I, probably, create `~/.emacs` file for such settings (it's missing now)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`set-frame-font` sets the font of the current frame. To set the default font for all frames, include the following line in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, set the [`font` parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html) in [`default-frame-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Initial-Parameters.html):

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             '(font . "-adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--12-120-75-75-m-70-iso8859-1"))
```

`~/.emacs` is the traditional location for Emacs's configuration file. `~/.emacs.d/init.el` is an alternate name with exactly the same role. Use either (but not both).

For X displays (i.e. on unix, or on non-unix systems using an X server), you can also set the font through [X resources](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/X-Resources.html). On many systems, `~/.Xresources` is read when you log in, and you can write there:

```
Emacs.font: -adobe-courier-medium-r-normal--12-120-75-75-m-70-iso8859-1
```

Comment: [Congrats on the 10K](http://stackathlon.appspot.com/).

Comment: Yay, finally a working answer for this.  set-default-font ...?
No, that would be too simple!

Comment: Type `M-x customize-option`, enter `Customize variable: default-frame-alist` , click `INS`, enter `Parameter: font` and `Value: 
"-outline-Droid Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-mono-13-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1"` (note surrounding `"` for font), click `State` and `Save for Future Sessions`

Answer (score 7):

`set-frame-font` takes two optional arguments: `KEEP-SIZE` and `FRAMES`. If  `FRAMES` is set to a non-nil value then the font is applied to future frames.

```
(set-frame-font "Inconsolata-13" t t)
```

I'm not sure how long this has been the case, but it's true as of Emacs 24.4.1.