# How to open .clj files with emacs from the command line with syntax coloring?

Tags: emacs

When I open `.clj` files from the command line with

```
$ emacs handler.clj
```

I see a screen that says something about errors opening the file, but a moment later the file opens but without syntax coloring. When I open the same file from emacs all is fine.

Is this how it is supposed to be? I cannot read what the error page says, it goes too fast.

Comment: The error page should still be available if you switch to the messages buffer. You can cycle through open buffers with `C-X Right` (that's the right arrow button).

Comment: @terdon Yes, I found the messages, it was apparently `(set-default-font "Monaca 16" nil t)` in my `.emacs` is causing the problem. I put the debugging info here: http://superuser.com/questions/692173/emacs-default-font-does-not-work-with-new-frames

Comment: ***`Monaco`, not `Monaca`.***  Look at the actual error message (and perhaps show it here).  What is it telling you is wrong with your `set-default-font` sexp? Is it just the spelling mistake?  (And there is no reason to spread this problem over multiple SO "questions" like you have done.  Post a more specific and precise question next time -- just one, instead of essentially a vague "Something doesn't work!?!!")